# How to replace strings using regex in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a string that sometimes contains strings like: @"[id123123|Some Name]"
What I have to do, is to simply replace it to "Some Name"

For example I have string: Some text lalala blabla **[id123|Some Name]** bla bla bla

And I need to get: Some text lalala blabla **Some Name** bla bla bla

The question is how to? My mind tells me that I can do this with NSRegularExpression

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this. Simply split the string on the vertical bar and remove the trailing close bracket.

Comment: Is there a chance that the rest of the text contains either **[**, or **]** or **|** ? If not, then you probably don't need a regex but simply split the string and rebuild it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an Objective C person, but judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903608/nsregularexpression-replace-url-text-with-a-tags) previous SO post, you could use a regex like so:

```
NSString *regexToReplaceRawLinks = @"\\[.+?\\|(.+?)\\]";   

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:regexToReplaceRawLinks
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];

NSString *string = @"[id123|Some Name]";

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1"];
```

This should match the string you are using and place the name in a group. You then replace the entire string `[id123|Some Name]` with `Some Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Look into `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`. The `options:` allow the search string to be a regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oQ3aL4/3)

```
(\[[^|]+|([^\]]+]))
```

**Description**

```
\[ matches the character [ literally
[^|]+ match a single character not present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
| the literal character |
\| matches the character | literally
1st Capturing group ([^\]]+])
    [^\]]+ match a single character not present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \] matches the character ] literally
    ] matches the character ] literally
```

In capture group 1 is the thing you want to replace with what is in capture group 2.  enjoy.